# Ionic - get RGB values from image

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

I am trying to get RGB values from picture without success.

For taking picture I am using `cordova-plugin-camera-preview` plugin.

Then I am displaying pic in `img` element from `base64string`.

Ater that I am trying to crop part of the image which I am interested in and display in `canvas` element.

Untill this point it is working fine, but failing to get RGB values for part of image displayed in canvas. `data` contains only "0" and taken image is not black (so values should be !=0)

Any help much appreciated.

home.ts

```
var canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
var image = new Image();
if (canvas.getContext) {
 var imgX = 312;
 var imgY = 408;
 var imgWidth = 60;
 var imgHeight = 296;
 var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 console.log('ctx = ' + ctx);
 var imageData = ctx.getImageData(312, 408, 60, 296);

 image.onload = function(){
  ctx.drawImage(image, 312,408 , 60,304 , 0,0 , 60,304);
 };

 image.src = this.base64Image;
 var imageData = new ImageData(imgWidth, imgHeight);

 imageData = ctx.getImageData(312, 408, imgWidth, imgHeight);
 console.log('imageData: ' + imageData.data[1]);
 var data = imageData.data;
 console.log('data: '+ data[0]);
}
```

`console.log('imageData: ' + imageData.data[1]);` and `console.log('data: '+ data[0]);` giving "0" value.

home.html

```
<img id ="image" class="image-container" src="{{base64Image}}" />
<canvas style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;" id="imageCanvas" ></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `imageData.data` returns a `Uint8ClampedArray` representing a one-dimensional array containing the data in the RGBA order, with integer values between 0 and 255 (included). This means you have to iterate over the resulting array and obtain the RGB values.

You can do that with a simple for loop:

```
for (var pixel = 0; pixel < data.length; pixel += 4) {
    var r = pixel[0];
    var g = pixel[1];
    var b = pixel[2];

    console.log("R:", r, "G:", g, "B:", b)
}
```

Comment: in general you right, but my problem is that if i get console.log for data like `console.log(data[0]) ` which should return 1st element of RGBA array i am getting "0" which means it is black/empty. Your code will serve well if i want specific pixel data. Problem is that my `data = imageData.data` seems to be filled in with "0" only - correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What `data.length` returns?